# C Program File/Folder search recurrsion

Tags: c

My program only cycles through 1 folder deep. When I run it, the program outputs the name of the folder 1 folder deep rather then entering it and listing its files.

```
void getFilesInDirectory(char *loc){
struct dirent *dirp;
DIR *rec;
struct stat f_info;
char full[PATH_MAX + 1];

rec = opendir(loc);
while ((dirp = readdir(rec)) != NULL)
{
    if(strcmp(dirp->d_name,".") != 0 && strcmp(dirp->d_name,"..") != 0){
        stat(dirp->d_name, &f_info);
        _fullpath(full, dirp->d_name, PATH_MAX);

        if(S_ISDIR(f_info.st_mode)){
            getFilesInDirectory(full);
        }else{
            printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);
        }
    }
}
close(rec);
}
```

Output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
folder1
folder2
```

Inside folder 1 and folder 2 is file3.txt and file4.txt respectively, but the program does not list them. So my output should be

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
```

is there a reason why the recursion stops 1 folder deep

Comment: Are you sure? I don't see a problem. Try debugger.

Comment: _fullpath probably works at the current directory level.  Try concatenating the dir name to the filename separated by a /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're calling stat() with the wrong filename. You need to pass it the full filename - it has no idea that you're looking at files in the "loc" directory.

```
sprintf(full,"%s/%s",loc,dirp->d_name);
stat(full, &f_info);
```

I also can't see how your _fullpath function could work, since you're not passing it loc

Comment: stat call works. i tried your suggestion and it gave same results. dirp->d_name is the relative path

Comment: nevermind this was it. I messed up my application of it. I forgot to change my recursion to include your new full file name. Thanks, this was it. The _fullpath works because dirp->d_name is the relative path from the CWD